# spinner с данными из SparseArray падает в NullPointerException

Tags: android, adapter

Сам spinner

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

как заполняю его данными (с мускула):

```
public class ask_phone extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private  FillMap loader; ///объект класса
public SparseStringsAdapter adapter;
SparseArray mCities = new SparseArray(); /// id,naim

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ask_phone);

///выдернем данные о городах
    loader = new FillMap();
    loader.execute("http://somesite.ru/get_data.php?_mode=getCity");
}

       ///класс для получаения данных с внешнего ресурса и заполнения выпадающего списка данными
 private class FillMap extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String resultJson = "";

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
// получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
                    try {

                        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    /// Log.d(LOG_TAG,"inputStream "+inputStream);
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                           buffer.append(line);
                    }

                    resultJson = buffer.toString();
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                    return resultJson;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "o fack " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "-1";
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }

            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
                if (s != "-1")
                    try {
                        dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(s);
                        int success = dataJsonObj.getInt("success");
                        if (success == 1) { ///если данные удалось достать
                            String _mode = dataJsonObj.getString("_mode");
                            switch (_mode) {
                                case "getCity":
                                    ///вытаскиваем все города
                                    JSONArray cities = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("cities");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < cities.length(); i++) {
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject city = cities.getJSONObject(i);
                                            int wId = city.getInt("id");

                                            String city_name =  city.getString("city_name");

                                            mCities.put(wId,city_name);

                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "shit 1" + e);
                                        }
                                    }


                                    // адаптер

                                     adapter = new SparseStringsAdapter(ask_phone.this,mCities);
                                   /// adapter.

                                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    // заголовок
                                    spinner.setPrompt("Список городов");
                                    // выделяем элемент
                                    spinner.setSelection((int) (MapsActivity.mCity-1));
                                    // устанавливаем обработчик нажатия
                                    cityId = adapter.getItemId(1);
                                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                           /// Toast.makeText(ask_phone.this, adapter.getItem(position)+"-"+adapter.getItemId(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            cityId = adapter.getItemId(position);
                                        }


                                        @Override
                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                                        }
                                    });

                                    break;

                            }
                        }///of if

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }



public abstract class SparseArrayAdapter<E> extends BaseAdapter {
/// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677866/how-to-use-sparsearray-as-a-source-for-adapter?answertab=votes#tab-top
    private SparseArray<E> mData;
    public void setData(SparseArray<E> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public E getItem(int position) {
        return mData.valueAt(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mData.keyAt(position);
    }
}

public class SparseStringsAdapter extends SparseArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public SparseStringsAdapter(Context context, SparseArray<String> data) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        setData(data);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView result = (TextView) convertView;
        if (result == null) {
            result = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"result = "+result.getId());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getItem(position) = "+getItem(position));
       result.setText(getItem(position));
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Падает на строке **result.setText(getItem(position));** (в самом низу), хотя логи выше этой строки выдают какие-то данные.

Когда этот класс наследовал от Activity, то все работало, но в нем не показывается ActionBar, а AppCompatActivity валится с ошибкой.

Подскажите как заставить его работать

**upd**
Stacktrace:

```
0java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference
1   at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7048)
2   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4070)
3   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3928)
4   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3903)
5   at com.example.necro.googlemaps.ask_phone$SparseStringsAdapter.getView(ask_phone.java:500)
6   at android.widget.BaseAdapter.getDropDownView(BaseAdapter.java:71)
7   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(AppCompatSpinner.java:624)
8   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(AppCompatSpinner.java:620)
9   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.measureHeightOfChildrenCompat(ListViewCompat.java:290)
10  at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1200)
11  at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:584)
12  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:766)
13  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:424)
14  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20101)
15  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
16  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
17  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
18  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
19  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
20  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
21  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
22  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Comment: а можно поподробнее текст ошибки

Comment: Опубликуйте решение в виде ответа. Вопрос только для собственно проблемы, а не ее решения.

Comment: тут замечал одну особенность: если взять адаптер из моего же ответа, но размерность массива строк (который для хранения отображаемых данных используется) сделать больше, чем этих самых данных - та же ошибка падает. В отладчике смотрел SparseArray, там ключей было сразу 13 (у меня 3 строки занято), хотя size() показывает 3... Мож тут закавырка...

Answer (score 1):

в общем так и не вышло у меня победить этот баг. Обошел костылем:
создал массив строк, забил туда отображаемые данные, а в первоначальном SparseArray стал хранить id из базы данных и номер позиции, соответсвующей сохраненной строке.

адаптер теперь такой используется:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ask_phone.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tmpCities);
                                       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setPrompt("Список городов");

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
cityId = mCities.keyAt(position);
Log.d(LOG_TAG,"city id = "+cityId);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
});
```